# Cancelled Azure Bizspark subscription how to reopen?

Tags: azure, bizspark

Our Bizspark subscription is cancelled in Azure but I can't reactivate it. I can't download any data from our sql databases or anywhere to transfer the data to another subscription.

The reactivate link is missing from our site.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-subscription-become-disable

Comment: I don't think you will find any help here as this is not a programming related question. I would recommend reaching out to Azure support and they should be able sort this issue out for you. Here's a link that you can use in case you're not able to create a support request via portal: http://aka.ms/azureportalhelp .

Comment: Yes this is in wrong site but if the azure subscription is free than you have to call the Microsoft help to reactivate it and change it to pay-as-you-go subscription. Users can not do it for there self.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about managing a subscription